# Item for in-app-purchase can not be found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to set up in-app-purchase for my app but I always get the message that the item can not be found.

This is what I did:

- published the apk to google as an alpha version
- created an in-app-item and activated it
- created a test account and added it in the google developer console
- Loaded the apk to the test device via Eclipse with the test account (the device has only one account and it is not the developer account)

This is my code for the in app-purchase. It is not yet finished yet but do it should do it for testing purposes:

```
    public static void UnlockProVersion2(Context context, final Activity activity)
{
    //...

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trying to unlock Pro-Version");

    final IabHelper mHelper;
    mHelper = new IabHelper(context, key);

    final IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() 
    {
      @Override
       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
       {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Purchasing: finished");
          if (result.isFailure()) 
          {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
          }      
          else if (purchase.getSku().equals("unlock_all_features")) 
          {
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Successfully unlocked all features");
          }
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "purchasing code: " + result);
       }
    };

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() 
    {
       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
       {
          if (!result.isSuccess()) 
          {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
          }  
          else
          {
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting up In-app Billing succeded");

             // Buy unlocked version
             mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, "unlock_all_features", 10001,   
                     mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? This is nearly driving me insane :(.

Another question: Shouldn't my test account be able to load the alpha version of the app from google play store? Although I think I've set up everything correctly my test user can not find the app in the play store. Is there any special link to alpha apps?

The dev console says that I should send 'following' link to the test usere but there is not 'following link'.

Any help is really appreciated.

---

***Edit:***
Here is a screenshot from my product in the dev console:
[image]

---

***Edit-2:***
If I got it right I should find a link to the alpha version on google play which I can provide to my testers.

Unfortunately there is not such a link as you can see on the screenshot. It is in german but as you can see there is no link. It just states: Send the following link to your testers, but there is no following link.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A draft APK was enough to test in-app billing before but Google recently changed it so now you have to publish it (in the alpha or beta channel) before testing.

First make sure that the app is released in the alpha channel: You need to press the "Publish now" button in the alpha testing tab to publish it to Google Play. It will be published for alpha testers only.

Then create a Google Group or Google Plus Community to which you add the test user. As the test user go to the URL provided in Google Play and opt in to be an alpha tester. Then you can install the package via the Google Play Store on your test device as the test user.

Once installed via Google Play you can test the whole IAB purchasing process. As long as you use the same version code and sign the APK properly you can update the package on the device directly via ADB without having to go through Google Play again. This saves hours in turn-around time.

Answer (score 1):

Install the same signed apk that you have uploaded for alpha version from terminal 
`adb install yourSignedApk.apk` on your device. And make sure that either you are login on the play store of the device using your test account only that you have register on google developer console or add your device default google account to the test account on developer console.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I can connect to google play but if I query for products I get an empty result set and if I try to buy a product I get an error that the product could not be found.

Comment: have you created and published your item "unlock_all_features" on developer console??

Comment: Yes, I've added a screenshot of my dev console to my original post.

Comment: It seems your product sku is "(unlock_all_features)" including bracket.

Comment: This is just the way it is displayed in the dev console. The sku contains no brackets. When I click on the product to see the details, the sku is shown without brackets.

Comment: The three things that are required to test in-app-purchase - app published in beta/alpha mode, email id of test users added to the developer console, and the product in published state. make sure all the things are in place.

Comment: I don't get it... all three things are in place but it does not work. When I query my product(s) I get an empty DETAILS_LIST: `skuDetails: Bundle[{DETAILS_LIST=[], RESPONSE_CODE=0}]`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make test purchases from the same device that you have registered with your developer email. Go into your device and sign into a new email, or use another device to test.

Also, you will have to install the signed apk directly from the alpha page to test purchases. Purchases will not work if you push it from eclipse.

Comment: I'm testing on a special test device. It has only one account and it is not the developer account. The test account is also added to the dev console. How can I install the `apk` from the alpha page? I used `adb` but this did not work either.

Comment: @user1567896 You need to create a Google Group or Google Plus Community to which you add the test user. Then, as the test user, you need to opt in to be an alpha tester. Then you can install the package via the Google Play Store on your test device.

Comment: @user1567896 Check out this page for details: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: @Hans Kratz How can the user opt in as an alpha tester? The user is in my testers google group and is added to the testers in the dev console. Does he has to do anything else to opt in as an alpha tester? There is only one account on the test device.

Comment: @user1567896 Yes. Please read the document at the URL I posted in my comment carefully, in particular this: "The Developer Console will give you a URL that you need to give to the users. They’ll need to go to the URL, which will explain what it means to be a tester and they can opt in."

Comment: I don't undestang - i need actually do publish the app first ?" The link that your testers can use to opt-in will be displayed here when you have published your app."

Comment: @Hans Kratz I don't see any link when I only have an alpha version. Where can I find this link?

Comment: click on "alpa testing" - > Manage list of testers - > under "Testers opting in"

Comment: So I opted in my test-group but there is no link to the alpha version that I could provide to my testers as you can see in the screenshot which I've added in my original post.

Comment: Seems your APK is not released in the alpha channel. You need to press the "Publish now" button in the alpha testing tab to publish it to Google Play. It will be published for alpha testers only.

Comment: @HansKratz So I have to upload my app images, edit the descriptions etc. and then publish the app with an apk in the alpha channel? It is not sufficient to just upload the apk for testing purposes?

Comment: @user1567896 Yes you have to do all that. A few months ago a draft APK was enough to test in-app billing but they recently changed it so now you have to publish it before testing.

Comment: @HansKratz Thanks a lot for that hint. This issue costed my several days :(. If you put your comment into an answer I'll accept it. Many thanks again.